# How can I get pair of negative + positive value from a .xlsx table using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, excel-tables

I have an excel files that looks like this :

| N_order | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1137 | 258 |
| 1137 | -258 |
| 1137 | 258 |
| 1138 | 802 |
| 1139 | 983 |
| 1139 | 837 |
| 1139 | -837 |
| 1139 | -248 |

I want to do pair with negative and positive value, but only pair, as an example I want them to be linked like that :

| N_order | Amount | Link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1137 | 258 | linked |
| 1137 | -258 | linked |
| 1137 | 258 |  |
| 1138 | 802 |  |
| 1139 | 983 |  |
| 1139 | 837 | linked |
| 1139 | -837 | linked |
| 1139 | -248 |  |

how can I do it ? I tried this code :

```
df['link'] = ""
for i in range(len(df)):
    commande = df.at[i, 'N_order']
    montant = df.at[i, 'Amount']
    if montant > 0:
        match = df.loc[(df['N_order'] == commande) & (df['Amount'] == -montant)]
        if not match.empty:
            df.at[i, 'link'] = commande
            df.at[match.index[0], 'link'] = commande
df = df[(df['N_order'] != '') & (df['link'] != '') & (df['Amount'] != '')][['N_order', 'Amount', 'link']]
df.to_excel("fileoutput.xlsx", index=False)
df
```

but it makes my table looks like that :

| N_order | Amount | Link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1137 | 258 | linked |
| 1137 | -258 | linked |
| 1137 | 258 | linked |
| 1138 | 802 |  |
| 1139 | 983 |  |
| 1139 | 837 | linked |
| 1139 | -837 | linked |
| 1139 | -248 |  |

(there is 1750 rows, so I can't just hand correct it.)

How can I do it ?
Thanks you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De-duplicate (with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the absolute values and [`sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) to identify the matching indices, then assign the comment:

```
import numpy as np

idx = (df
   .assign(n=df.groupby(['N_order', 'Amount']).cumcount(),
           sign=np.sign(df['Amount']),
           abs=df['Amount'].abs()
          )
   .reset_index()
   .pivot(index=['N_order', 'n', 'abs'], columns='sign', values='index')
   .reindex([-1, 1], axis=1)
   .dropna().to_numpy().ravel()
)

df.loc[idx, 'Link'] = 'linked'
```

Output:

```
   N_order  Amount    Link
0     1137     258  linked
1     1137    -258  linked
2     1137     258     NaN
3     1138     802     NaN
4     1139     983     NaN
5     1139     837  linked
6     1139    -837  linked
7     1139    -248     NaN
```

Intermediate pivot of the indices:

```
sign            -1    1
N_order n abs          
1137    0 258  1.0  0.0
        1 258  NaN  2.0
1138    0 802  NaN  3.0
1139    0 248  7.0  NaN
          837  6.0  5.0
          983  NaN  4.0
```

###### bonus: matching the paired value

With a minor modification you can also match the index of the paired values:

```
df2 = (df.assign(n=df.groupby(['N_order', 'Amount']).cumcount(),
           sign=np.sign(df['Amount']),
           abs=df['Amount'].abs()
          )
   .reset_index()
   .pivot(index=['N_order', 'n', 'abs'], columns='sign', values='index')
   .reindex([-1, 1], axis=1)
   .dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
)

df['matching_index'] = pd.concat([df2.set_index(-1)[1], df2.set_index(1)[-1]])
```

Output:

```
   N_order  Amount  matching_index
0     1137     258             1.0
1     1137    -258             0.0
2     1137     258             NaN
3     1138     802             NaN
4     1139     983             NaN
5     1139     837             6.0
6     1139    -837             5.0
7     1139    -248             NaN
```

Comment: Thanks you, it actually work ! Now I just need to find out how to deal with 0 inside "Amount". Because when there is a 0 inside it every value of Link is "NaN"

Comment: I see, then add `.reindex([-1, 1], axis=1)` just before  `dropna` (see update)

Comment: @mozway https://stackoverflow.com/a/75332774/20284103

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `rolling()` to find the values that add to 0 to locate the linked pair.

```
a = df.groupby('N_order')['Amount'].rolling(2,min_periods = 1).sum()

s = a.droplevel(0).eq(0) & df['Amount'].lt(0)

df['Link'] = np.where(s.where(s).bfill(limit=1).fillna(False),'linked','')
```

Output:

```
   N_order  Amount    Link
0     1137     258  linked
1     1137    -258  linked
2     1137     258        
3     1138     802        
4     1139     983        
5     1139     837  linked
6     1139    -837  linked
7     1139    -248
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will fail if the data is not sorted, or duplicates not in a very particular order, see for instance `pd.DataFrame({'N_order': [1137, 1137, 1137, 1137, 1137, 1138, 1138, 1138, 1139, 1139, 1139, 1139], 'Amount': [257, 258, 258, -258, -258, 802, 204, -802, 983, 837, -837, -248]})` ;)

Comment: ahh, i might have misinterpreted the question. i thought the positive negative combo was required to be next to each other.

Comment: Fair enough, I would be surprised, but the example is ambiguous. If this was the case then my approach wouldn't work as it's designed to be independent of the order. (If it's not a pre-requisite but the data is anyway always in this order, then both approaches work).

Comment: yeah i guess ill leave my answer up just in case. I also wanted to say, you have some of the best solutions to all these pandas questions, and I always look out for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    ss1=dd.Amount.abs().duplicated(keep=False)
    return dd.assign(Link=np.where(ss1,"linked",""))

df1.assign(col1=df1.groupby(['N_order', 'Amount']).cumcount())\
    .groupby(['N_order',"col1"],as_index=False).apply(function1).drop("col1",axis=1)
```

out

```
    N_order  Amount    Link
0     1137     258  linked
1     1137    -258  linked
2     1137     258        
3     1138     802        
4     1139     983        
5     1139     837  linked
6     1139    -837  linked
7     1139    -248
```